# CKEditor striping class names only when multiple classes defined

Tags: class, ckeditor

Have seen all the posts that suggest setting :

```
CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
```

But that doesn't apply in this case. CKEditor is not stripping class names when a single class name is being used. This is ok for example :

```
class="red"
```

However when multiple class names are used, like this:

class="red small left"

Then after saving it's converted to this :

```
class="red" small="" left=""
```

Anyone seen that before and worked out a fix? CKEditor 4

Comment: Which version of CKEditor? Which browser (also version number)? JSFiddle? It looks like some problem with quotation marks (`"..."`) but it's hard to tell if this is frontend or backend issue. Does CKEditor return valid html (`CKEDITOR.instances.instanceName.getData()`)? You should focus on your backend if it is so.

Comment: Well done mate, you were right. I was using a different parsing function which was stripping the quotes.